# Cannot bind to the new display member C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, function, combobox

I have previously researched this topic which lead me to adding this line of code to my program.

```
public static string Options { get; set; }
```

However, I still get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember'

I have created this function in order to fill up two separate comboboxes (one of all the drinks and one off all the food). This information is provided to the program from two separate tables. The variable 'Option' will either be assigned Drink or Food which will decide what information is shown.

Here is the complete function:

```
    public static void FillFoodCombo(ComboBox combobox, string Option)
    {
        Options = Option + "_Name";

        string Query = "SELECT " + Options + " FROM Food";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, LogInForm.connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, Options);
        combobox.DisplayMember = Options;
        combobox.ValueMember = Options;
        combobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[Options];
    }
```

Sorry if this is just me being thick :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options = Option + "_name";
```

And then assign like this:

```
combobox.DisplayMember = Options;
```

Comment: I made this change and I do not receive the error on the combobox.DisplayMember line, however, I now receive it on the combobox.ValueMember line?

Comment: Did you do the change for both? So update combobox.ValueMember = Options; aswell?

Comment: Yes, I will update my question to show the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Your table name is hard coded in the query string

```
string Query = "SELECT " + Options + " FROM Food";
```

Also, try changing the order of statements as:

```
    combobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[Options];
    combobox.DisplayMember = Options;
    combobox.ValueMember = Options;
```